# Error: Missing app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/ error Expo bare-minimum workflow

Tags: react-native, expo

when I run expo start after installing my dependencies and doing yarn start then I get below 2 error messages

```
Error: Missing app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/
No Expo configuration found. Are you sure this is a project directory?
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong as I have followed the steps mentioned in the bare workflow documentation.

**Please Note** :- Please Note :- My expo version is 2.11.7 My NPM version is 6.5.0 My node version is 11.9.0

Any assistance on this will be appreciated

Comment: Are you run it from project directory?

Comment: yes I am running it from project directory